# How do I get my EC2 account balance programatically?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm looking to get my account balance programatically from AWS. I found DevPay & FPS in the documentation, but they don't seem to apply to *my* account, but rather my customers'. I'd hate to scrape the [account screen](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?ie=UTF8&action=activity-summary), but I'll do it, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately neither AWS nor any other IaaS/PaaS/SaaS vendor I'm aware of does offer API access to their accounting data currently (maybe due to the potential financial/legal implications) - 
see my longer answer on [How can I monitor daily spending on AWS?](https://serverfault.com/a/350991/10305) for an interesting alternative to scraping the account screen yourself.