# What is DynamoDB number and string data type storage space

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What is the storage space for a number type in DynamoDB `Number` vs `string` type?

Say I have a number (1234789). If I store it as `number` type, then it will take just 4 bytes, and as `string` it will take 7 bytes?

Does DynamoDB stores all numbers as bigdecimal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ItemSize in DynamoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988389/itemsize-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDb is a managed cloud service, so I think the way that they store data internally is not clear.

However, they transfer Numbers as Strings for language compatibility support and one of the things that affect RCU/WCU is transfer data size.

So, as far as your concern is about calculating provisioned throughput and costs, Number size should be considered as a String size.

Answer (score 0):

As Per [DynamoDB Documentation : Datatypes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) :

> **String**
>
> Strings are Unicode with UTF-8 binary encoding. The length of a string
>   must be greater than zero, and is constrained by the maximum DynamoDB
>   item size limit of 400 KB.
>
> If you define a primary key attribute as a string type attribute, the
>   following additional constraints apply:
>
> 1. For a simple primary key, the maximum length of the first attribute value (the partition key) is 2048 bytes.
> 2. For a composite primary key, the maximum length of the second attribute value (the sort key) is 1024 bytes.
>
> **Number**
>
> Numbers can be positive, negative, or zero. Numbers can have up to 38
>   digits precision—exceeding this will result in an exception.
>
> 1. Positive range: 1E-130 to 9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125
> 2. Negative range: -9.9999999999999999999999999999999999999E+125 to -1E-130
>
> **In DynamoDB, numbers are represented as variable length. Leading and
>   trailing zeroes are trimmed.**
>
> **All numbers are sent across the network to DynamoDB as strings, to
>   maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However,
>   DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical
>   operations.**
>
> **Note :** If number precision is important, you should pass numbers to DynamoDB using strings that you convert from number type.

I Hope, this may help you get your answer.

Comment: @user1846749, Did this help you to resolve your question ?

Comment: how many bytes will a number Sort Key consume in storage?