# Check ItemSize DynamoDB in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I use the dynamo set function to store data in DynamoDB, but sometimes the data is too big. Is there a function that I can use to determine if the data is too big to be saved in DynamoDB? a Node js function? Thanks

This should work even if the data is an object with arrays and other objects.

I tried to npm module object-sizeof, does that work?

Comment: Do you mean whether the data exceeds 400 KB max size?

Comment: yes how do I check that the data doesn't exist 400Kb

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`dyno-item-size`** module to get the item size.

```
var dynoItemSize = require('dyno-item-size');
var size = dynoItemSize(item);

var params = {
    TableName : table,
    Item : {
        "autoID" : "yyy",
        "alexandriaID" : "id1",
        "docType" : "foo",
        "username" : "good",
        "userdescription" : "user description",
        "comment" : "complex condition"
    }
};

console.log("Size of item =====>" + dynoItemSize(params.Item));
```

**References:-**

[ItemSize in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988389/itemsize-in-dynamodb)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html

> An item size is the sum of lengths of its attribute names and values
>   (binary and UTF-8 lengths);

Comment: this doesn't work when your Item has arrays and objects. Is there another way?

Comment: How are you saying this doesnt work for array and object? Can you give an example?

Comment: and Item that has an array for a key and an object for another key

Comment: Thanks! Better provide the sample item and expected result. Will check with the above apis and let you know.