# Calculate size of items in my Amazon DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'd like to figure out the size of items in my Amazon DynamoDB table or the full size so i can accurately forecast costs in a project I'm working on.

I understand that for every 4kb of data read it will use 1RCU. So now id like to find out the size for every entry or the total table.

Comment: Please reference https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988389/5787099

Comment: @Jeff thanks, where would I find the aggregate table size?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. I didnt realize you were looking for total size of the table, just size of each item

Answer (score 13):

The AWS Command "describe-table" will give you metadata for the given table.

```
aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name [table name]
```

The output will have a parameter

```
"TableSizeBytes": 0,
```

Which will give you "The total size of the specified table, in bytes. DynamoDB updates this value approximately every six hours. Recent changes might not be reflected in this value."

Per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also find it out from the AWS console. As you can see in the attached image, it will show the total table size as well average item size.

You will find these details in the `Table -> Overview` section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this website to calculate the size of an item:

https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/